# org.sonar.duplications.DuplicationsException: Unable to build statement from token

Tags: java, jenkins, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I am breaking my head since last week for this one particular error. I am not able to find the solution for this error from anywhere from the world.

I am newly setting up sonar for my project.

while executing sonar-runner I am getting following error.. Can someone please help me what is the error was?

```
11:53:31.185 WARN  - Class 'ui/component/JXCollapsiblePane' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
11:53:31.187 INFO  - Java bytecode scan done: 10026 ms
11:53:31.374 INFO  - Package design analysis...
11:53:36.044 INFO  - Package design analysis done: 4670 ms
11:53:45.673 INFO  - Sensor JavaSquidSensor done: 63118 ms
11:53:45.673 INFO  - Sensor SurefireSensor...
11:53:45.675 INFO  - parsing /home/jenkins/.jenkins/workspace/CSF_Build/CRM/.sonar/build/surefire-reports
11:53:45.676 INFO  - Sensor SurefireSensor done: 3 ms
11:53:45.676 INFO  - Sensor CpdSensor...
11:53:45.676 INFO  - SonarEngine is used
11:53:45.847 INFO  - Cross-project analysis disabled
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 2:03.486s
INFO: Final Memory: 12M/452M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
ERROR: Unable to execute Sonar
ERROR: Caused by: Unable to build statement from token : ''[301,2]
ERROR: Caused by: None of the statement channel has been able to consume token: ''[301,2]
ERROR:
ERROR: To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Sonar Runner with the -e switch.
ERROR: Re-run Sonar Runner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

Comment: Have you seen this post (http://sonarqube.15.x6.nabble.com/DuplicationsException-Unable-to-build-statement-from-token-td5013947.html) ? In that case a stray character had creapt into a config file causing that error. Also, have you tried "Re-run Sonar Runner using the -X switch" as it suggests in the message?

Answer (score 3):

I have identified the issue.

One of the java file was checked in into the code repository with wrong character set. the code scan was ejected while scaning this java file